# onclick event inside table and foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, onclick

I want to allow clicking on a whole host table in foreach loop in codeigniter. For some reason, the code does not work for me. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>השולח</th>
            <th>נשלחה בתאריך</th>
            <th>נושא ההודעה</th>
            <th>תוכן ההודעה</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


       <?php foreach ($messages->result() as $row)
             { 
       ?> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                   function newDoc() {
                       window.location.assign("<?php echo base_url();?>/read_messages/<?php echo $row->id;?>")
                   }
                </script>

       <?php

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row->author. "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->posted_in. "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->title. "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->body. "</td>";

       ?>

                onclick="newDoc()";

        <?php   
                echo "</tr>";   
              }
        ?>    

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question you want fetch click on every row. then your code should be as:

Your Script should be out side

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function newDoc(id) {
     window.location.assign("<?php echo base_url();?>/read_messages/"+id);
  }
</script>


<?php foreach ($messages->result() as $row)
      { 
                echo "<tr onclick='newDoc(".$row->id.")'>";
                echo "<td>".$row->author. "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->posted_in. "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->title. "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->body. "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";   
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign onClick="newDoc" to html element like

```html
<table onClick="newDoc()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to issues, one your `newDoc()` function is not assigned to element and two you want create the `newDoc` function once and only once passing in the `$row->id` so that its affect changes for each `<tr>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function newDoc(rowId) {
    window.location.assign("<?php echo base_url();?>/read_messages/" + rowId);
  }
</script>

<?php
 foreach ($messages->result() as $row) {
   echo "<tr  onlick='newDoc(<?php echo $row->id ?>)'>";
   echo "<td>".$row->author. "</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row->posted_in. "</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row->title. "</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row->body. "</td>";
   echo "</tr>"; 
 }
?>
```